# Binary Search Tree Difficulties

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

As part of an exercise, in my effort to try to learn Programming, i am asked to create a program that uses 
1. a structure
2. a doubled linked list
3. A Binary Search Tree

to create a database of customers..
I am ok with adding nodes, to the list and searching.
However when trying to delete a customer the program doesnt work as is should be and crashes.. 
I have tracked down the problem to be to my **BST_delete function** starting in line 86, because if i don't run this function the program works far better. 
In more detail i think that i am not updating correcty **BST_email_root** that should be the most recent node of the Binary tree..

This is driving me crazy! I know that it is not the most elegant code, but i am still trying to learn! Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING 250

void myflush();

// Defining a customer structure.
struct customer {
    char *name;
    char *address;
    char *email;
};

// A double linked list. The data field points to a customer struct.
struct double_linked_list {
    struct customer *data;
    struct double_linked_list *previous;
    struct double_linked_list *next;
};

// Defining a pointer for the first one of the customers in the double linked list.

struct double_linked_list *customers_head=0;

// A  node for a Binary Search Tree (BST).

struct BST_node {
    struct double_linked_list *data;
    struct BST_node *left;
    struct BST_node *right;
};

// Defining a variable for the root of the BST that is indexed by the email.
struct BST_node *BST_email_root = 0;

// Looking for a node with a specific email in the BST.

struct BST_node *BST_find_customer(struct BST_node *root, char *email) {
if (root==NULL)
    return NULL;
if (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email)==0)
    return root;
else
    {
    if (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email)==-1)
    return BST_find_customer(root->left,email);
    else
        return BST_find_customer(root->right,email);
    }
}

// A procedure to finding a customer according to his email.

void find_customer() {
    char email[MAX_STRING];
    struct double_linked_list *l;
    struct BST_node *b;
    printf("Give the email of the customer (up to %d characters) : ", MAX_STRING-1);
    gets(email);

    b = BST_find_customer(BST_email_root, email);
    if (b==0)
        printf("There is no customer with this email.\n");
    else
    {
        l = b->data;
        printf("Customer found! \n");
        printf("Name    : %s\n", l->data->name);
        printf("Address : %s\n", l->data->address);
        printf("Email   : %s\n", l->data->email);
    }
}

struct BST_node *findMaxNode(struct BST_node *root)
            {
                if(root->right == NULL) return root;
                findMaxNode(root->right);
            }

// Deleting a node in the BST, according to a given email.

// The function returns the (new?) root of the BST, which might have been changed or not.
struct BST_node *BST_delete(struct BST_node *root, char *email)
{

if (root==NULL)
    return root;
struct BST_node *father=NULL;
char which_son;
while (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email)!=0){ //first, finding root and remembering who's root father
if(root==NULL) {
     return root;
} else if (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email) <0){
     father = root;
     root = root->left;
     if(root==NULL)
        return;
     else which_son = 'l';
} else {
     father = root;
     root = root->right;
    if(root==NULL)
        return;
    else which_son = 'r';
}
}
// now you have both the root node, and its father
if ( (root->right == NULL) && (root->left == NULL) ){ //case 1, if it's a leaf
 free(root);

} else if (root->left == NULL) { //case 2
    if (which_son == 'l') {
        father->left = root->right;
    } else {
        father->right = root->right;
    }

} else { //case 3 : here i get the "rightest" son of root's left son
    struct BST_node *replacing_node = root->left;
    while (replacing_node->right != NULL) {
        replacing_node = replacing_node->right;
    } //now replacing_node is a leaf, and can replace root
    if (which_son == 'l') {
        father->left = replacing_node;
        replacing_node->left = root->left;
        replacing_node->right = root->right;
    } else {
        father->right = replacing_node;
        replacing_node->left = root->left;
        replacing_node->right = root->right;
    }
    }
    return root;
}


// This function adds a new node in the Binary Search Tree (BST) rooted by *root,

struct BST_node *new_BST_node(struct BST_node *root, struct double_linked_list *l)
    {
    if (root==NULL)
        {
        root= (struct BST_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct BST_node ));
        if (root==NULL)
            {
            printf("Out of Memory!");
            exit(1);
            }

        root->data=l;
        root->left=NULL;
        root->right=NULL;
        return root;
        }

    if ((strcmp(l->data->email,root->data->data->email))<0)
                root->left =new_BST_node(root->left,l);
    else
        root->right =new_BST_node(root->right,l);


    };


// A procedure to modify the data concerning an existing customer
void modify_customer() {
    char old_email[MAX_STRING];
    char new_email[MAX_STRING];
    char new_name[MAX_STRING];
    char new_address[MAX_STRING];
    char ans;

    struct BST_node *ind;
    struct double_linked_list *l;

    printf("Give the email of the customer you want to modify: ");
    gets(old_email);
    ind = BST_find_customer(BST_email_root, old_email);
    if (ind == 0)
    {
        printf("There is no customer with this email.\n");
        return;
    }

    l = ind->data;  // The node in the double linked list for the customer
    printf("Old name: %s\n", l->data->name);
    printf("Give the new name (up to %d characters, <Enter> if it does not change): ", MAX_STRING - 1);
    gets(new_name);
    if (new_name[0] == 0)
        strcpy(new_name, l->data->name);

    printf("Old address: %s\n", l->data->address);
    printf("Give the new address (up to %d characters, <Enter> if it does not change): ", MAX_STRING - 1);
    gets(new_address);
    if (new_address[0] == 0)
        strcpy(new_address, l->data->address);

    printf("Old email: %s\n", l->data->email);
    printf("Give the new email (up to %d characters, <Enter> if it does not change): ", MAX_STRING-1);
    gets(new_email);
    if (new_email[0] == 0)
        strcpy(new_email, l->data->email);

    if (strcmp(l->data->email, new_email))
    {
        if (BST_find_customer(BST_email_root, new_email))
        {
            printf("New email already exists. Modification aborted.\n");
            return;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("REPLACE:\n");
    printf("Name    : %s\n", l->data->name);
    printf("Address : %s\n", l->data->address);
    printf("Email   : %s\n", l->data->email);
    printf("WITH:\n");
    printf("Name    : %s\n", new_name);
    printf("Address : %s\n", new_address);
    printf("Email   : %s\n\n", new_email);

    printf("Are you sure? (Y)es/(N)o\n");
    scanf(" %c", &ans);
    myflush();
    if (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y')
    {
        free(l->data->name);
        l->data->name = strdup(new_name);
        free(l->data->address);
        l->data->address = strdup(new_address);

        if (strcmp(l->data->email, new_email) != 0)
            // Only in case the email has been changed, we have to maintain the BST
        {
            BST_email_root=BST_delete(BST_email_root, l->data->email);
            free(l->data->email);
            l->data->email = strdup(new_email);
            BST_email_root=new_BST_node(BST_email_root, l);
        }
    }
}

//  add a new customer
struct double_linked_list *new_customer()
{
    char name[MAX_STRING], address[MAX_STRING], email[MAX_STRING];
    struct BST_node *b;
    struct double_linked_list *l;
    struct customer *c;

    printf("\nADDING A CUSTOMER\n\n\n");
    printf("Give the name (up to %d characters): ", MAX_STRING-1);
    gets(name);

    printf("Give the address (up to %d characters): ", MAX_STRING - 1);
    gets(address);

    printf("Give the email (up to %d characters): ", MAX_STRING - 1);
    gets(email);

        // check for duplicate email
    b = BST_find_customer(BST_email_root, email);
    if (b)
    {
        printf("Duplicate email. Customer aborted.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    c = (struct customer *) malloc(sizeof(struct customer));
    if (c == 0)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    c->name = strdup(name); // check for memory allocation problem
    if (c->name == 0) return 0;
    c->address = strdup(address);   // check for memory allocation problem
    if (c->address == 0) return 0;
    c->email = strdup(email);   // check for memory allocation problem
    if (c->email == 0) return 0;

    l = (struct double_linked_list*) malloc(sizeof(struct double_linked_list));
    if (l == 0)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory.\n");
        free(c->name);
        free(c->address);
        free(c->email);
        free(c);
        return 0;
    }

    l->data = c;
    l->previous = 0;
    l->next = customers_head;

    if (customers_head)
        customers_head->previous = l;

    customers_head = l;

    BST_email_root = new_BST_node(BST_email_root, l);

    return l;
}

// This function deletes a customer, based on its email
void delete_customer() {
    char email[MAX_STRING];
    struct BST_node *n_del;
    printf("Give the email of the customer you want to delete(up to %d characters) : ", MAX_STRING-1);
    gets(email);

    n_del = BST_find_customer(BST_email_root, email);
    if (n_del==0)
        printf("There is no customer with this email.\n");

    else
    {
    struct double_linked_list *current = n_del->data;
    //struct double_linked_list *temp;
    //struct double_linked_list *prev = customers_head;

    if (current->next==NULL &&current->previous==NULL)
        {
        free(current);
        customers_head=0;
        }

    else if (current->next==NULL) //TA EXOUN ANAPODA??i oxi..Den exw katalaveiNEXT=0 EINAI GIA TO PROTO STOIXEIO pou vazw. An exw mono ena stoixeio ti ginete? prepei na to dw..
        {
        printf("1");
        current->previous->next=NULL;
        free(current);
        }

    else if (current->previous==NULL)
        { printf("2");
            current->next->previous=NULL;   //Apla kane to previous tou proigoumenou apo ton teleytaio pou thes na kaneis na mi deixnei pouthena..
        customers_head=current->next;
        free(current);
        }
    else
       {
        printf("3");
        current->next->previous = current->previous;  //vle ton proigoumeno komvo na deixnei ston epomeno kai ton epomeno ston proigoumeno
        current->previous->next = current->next;      //Ftiakse to customer's head na deixnei sto proigoumeno pou einai pleon to pio prosfato sti lista
       }
    }

    BST_email_root=BST_delete(BST_email_root, email);
}


void displaymenu() {
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("1. New customer\n");
    printf("2. Find customer using email\n");
    printf("3. Modify customer\n");
    printf("4. Delete customer\n");
    printf("0. Exit\n\n");
    printf("Give a choice (0-6) : ");
}

// This function empties the buffer of the standard input (stdin), that is, of the keyboard
void myflush()
{
    char ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
}


// The main function
int main() {
    int choice;
    do {
        displaymenu();
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        myflush();
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            new_customer();
            break;
        case 2:
            find_customer();
            break;
        case 3:
            modify_customer();
            break;
        case 4:
            delete_customer();
            break;

        default:
            printf("Wrong selection.\n\n");
        }
    } while (choice != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Goodness me! You have linked lists and trees and the data is struct with allocated memory pointers. An answer has spotted one problem. Meanwhile get busy with the debugger. BTW did you build your program step be tiny step, checking and stretching as you go, or did it fall over after a massive overnight coding effort?

Comment: Not an answer, but a possible bug sighting:  In `BST_delete`, the second `if(root==NULL)` check leads to `return ;`.  It should be returning a `struct BST_node *` of some sort.  Even if that pointer is `NULL`, you should say so explicitly.  (The indenting gets weird around that line, too...  Cut and paste error, maybe?)

Comment: One error found... With a debugger !!! In the function `BST_delete()` when looping in the `while (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email)!=0)`, you are not checking `if(root==NULL)` after `root = root->left;` or `root = root->right;` and `root->data` failed !!!

Comment: Well, i was given some code, and i complete the functions, which proves to be more difficult than if i was building the code from scratch! The code works ok, until you try to delete something.. So i am updating the code with your suggestions, however still have a lot of work with the debugger to make it working! Or i should reconsider a restructure of the delete functions maybe...

Comment: @WeatherVane, Mr ritgeo is really working step-by-step... or question-by-question. First Q ["Pointers and binary search tree"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779396/pointers-and-binary-search-tree), Second Q ["Algorithmic improvement for finding minimum sum in a Binary Search Tree"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795365/algorithmic-improvement-for-finding-minimum-sum-in-a-binary-search-tree) and now **"Binary Search Tree Difficulties"** !!!

Comment: @J.Piquard you are on the case then!

Comment: I fixed everything but still no luck.. I think that i am not returning the correct value from this function. It is supposed to only return a value when the "head" of the BST node gets erased.. I will look into this, and probably start all over again, with the use of a pen and a paper, to see what i am missing :) ..

Comment: *still no luck* : **isolate** the problem. (binary) trees are easy, double linked lists are hard. Choose your victims.

Comment: I highly recommend Eric Lippert's "[How To Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" for advice on isolating bugs like this one.  It's one of several good articles listed at the bottom of the Help Center's "[ask]".

Answer (score 2):

Without diving to deep into your code, there's one thing that I saw immediately. Your statement

```
...  if (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email) == -1) {
```

assumes that if the one is smaller than the other, the return value is exactly `-1`. The return value of `strcmp` in this case is, however, just guaranteed to be `< 0`,  not exactly `-1` (cf. [strcmp reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)).

Hence, it is likely that, while searching for the "father", you do not find the node you are looking for...

Comment: Will try it and get back! Thank to you sir!

Comment: This was code, that i missed because i was concentrated on the delete function, and not on the find function, so i have not spotted it out! Sorry should have been more carefull!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my modified version. I think the double_linked_list is not needed. You can directly use customer for BST_node.data. I tested add new customer, find customer, delete customer and all worked as expected. But I didn't test modifying a customer which I think is rather straight forward.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING 250

void myflush();

// Defining a customer structure.
struct customer {
    char *name;
    char *address;
    char *email;
};

// A double linked list. The data field points to a customer struct.
struct double_linked_list {
    struct customer *data;
    struct double_linked_list *previous;
    struct double_linked_list *next;
};

// Defining a pointer for the first one of the customers in the double linked list.

struct double_linked_list *customers_head=0;

// A  node for a Binary Search Tree (BST).

struct BST_node {
    struct double_linked_list *data;
    struct BST_node *top;
    struct BST_node *left;
    struct BST_node *right;
};

// Defining a variable for the root of the BST that is indexed by the email.
struct BST_node *BST_email_root = 0;

// Looking for a node with a specific email in the BST.

struct BST_node *BST_find_customer(struct BST_node *root, char *email) {
if (root==NULL)
    return NULL;

int rv = strcmp(email,root->data->data->email);

if (rv==0)
    return root;
else
    {
    if (rv<0)
    return BST_find_customer(root->left,email);
    else
        return BST_find_customer(root->right,email);
    }
}

// A procedure to finding a customer according to his email.

void find_customer() {
    char email[MAX_STRING];
    struct double_linked_list *l;
    struct BST_node *b;
    printf("Give the email of the customer (up to %d characters) : ", MAX_STRING-1);
    gets(email);

    b = BST_find_customer(BST_email_root, email);
    if (b==0)
        printf("There is no customer with this email.\n");
    else
    {
        l = b->data;
        printf("Customer found! \n");
        printf("Name    : %s\n", l->data->name);
        printf("Address : %s\n", l->data->address);
        printf("Email   : %s\n", l->data->email);
    }
}

struct BST_node *findMaxNode(struct BST_node *root)
            {
                if(root->right == NULL) return root;
                findMaxNode(root->right);
                return NULL;
            }

// Deleting a node in the BST, according to a given email.

// The function returns the (new?) root of the BST, which might have been changed or not.
struct BST_node *BST_delete(struct BST_node *root, char *email)
    {

    if (root==NULL)
        return root;
    struct BST_node *father=NULL;
    char which_son;
    while (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email)!=0){ //first, finding root and remembering who's root father
    if(root==NULL) {
         return NULL;
    } else if (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email) < 0){
         father = root;
         root = root->left;
         which_son = 'l';
    } else {
         father = root;
         root = root->right;
         which_son = 'r';
    }
}
    // now you have both the root node, and its father
    if ( (root->right == NULL) && (root->left == NULL) ){ //case 1, if it's a leaf
     free(root);

    } else if (root->left == NULL) { //case 2
        if (which_son == 'l') {
            father->left = root->right;
        } else {
            father->right = root->right;
        }

    } else { //case 3 : here i get the "rightest" son of root's left son
        struct BST_node *replacing_node = root->left;
        while (replacing_node->right != NULL) {
            replacing_node = replacing_node->right;
        } //now replacing_node is a leaf, and can replace root
        if (which_son == 'l') {
            father->left = replacing_node;
            replacing_node->left = root->left;
            replacing_node->right = root->right;
        } else {
            father->right = replacing_node;
            replacing_node->left = root->left;
            replacing_node->right = root->right;
        }
        }
        return root;
    }


// This function adds a new node in the Binary Search Tree (BST) rooted by *root,

void new_BST_node(struct BST_node *root, struct double_linked_list *l)
{
    if ((strcmp(l->data->email,root->data->data->email))<0)
    {
        if(root->left == NULL)
        {
            root->left = (struct BST_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct BST_node ));
            root->left->data = l;
            root->left->top = root;
            root->left->left = NULL;
            root->left->right = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            new_BST_node(root->left,l);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(root->right == NULL)
        {
            root->right = (struct BST_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct BST_node ));
            root->right->data = l;
            root->right->top = root;
            root->right->left = NULL;
            root->right->right = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            new_BST_node(root->right,l);
        }
    }
}


// A procedure to modify the data concerning an existing customer
void modify_customer() {
    char old_email[MAX_STRING];
    char new_email[MAX_STRING];
    char new_name[MAX_STRING];
    char new_address[MAX_STRING];
    char ans;

    struct BST_node *ind;
    struct double_linked_list *l;

    printf("Give the email of the customer you want to modify: ");
    gets(old_email);
    ind = BST_find_customer(BST_email_root, old_email);
    if (ind == 0)
    {
        printf("There is no customer with this email.\n");
        return;
    }

    l = ind->data;  // The node in the double linked list for the customer
    printf("Old name: %s\n", l->data->name);
    printf("Give the new name (up to %d characters, <Enter> if it does not change): ", MAX_STRING - 1);
    gets(new_name);
    if (new_name[0] == 0)
        strcpy(new_name, l->data->name);

    printf("Old address: %s\n", l->data->address);
    printf("Give the new address (up to %d characters, <Enter> if it does not change): ", MAX_STRING - 1);
    gets(new_address);
    if (new_address[0] == 0)
        strcpy(new_address, l->data->address);

    printf("Old email: %s\n", l->data->email);
    printf("Give the new email (up to %d characters, <Enter> if it does not change): ", MAX_STRING-1);
    gets(new_email);
    if (new_email[0] == 0)
        strcpy(new_email, l->data->email);

    if (strcmp(l->data->email, new_email))
    {
        if (BST_find_customer(BST_email_root, new_email))
        {
            printf("New email already exists. Modification aborted.\n");
            return;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("REPLACE:\n");
    printf("Name    : %s\n", l->data->name);
    printf("Address : %s\n", l->data->address);
    printf("Email   : %s\n", l->data->email);
    printf("WITH:\n");
    printf("Name    : %s\n", new_name);
    printf("Address : %s\n", new_address);
    printf("Email   : %s\n\n", new_email);

    printf("Are you sure? (Y)es/(N)o\n");
    scanf(" %c", &ans);
    myflush();
    if (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y')
    {
        free(l->data->name);
        l->data->name = strdup(new_name);
        free(l->data->address);
        l->data->address = strdup(new_address);

        if (strcmp(l->data->email, new_email) != 0)
            // Only in case the email has been changed, we have to maintain the BST
        {
            BST_email_root=BST_delete(BST_email_root, l->data->email);
            free(l->data->email);
            l->data->email = strdup(new_email);
            new_BST_node(BST_email_root, l);
        }
    }
}

//  add a new customer
struct double_linked_list *new_customer()
{
    char name[MAX_STRING], address[MAX_STRING], email[MAX_STRING];
    struct BST_node *b;
    struct double_linked_list *l;
    struct customer *c;

    printf("\nADDING A CUSTOMER\n\n\n");
    printf("Give the name (up to %d characters): ", MAX_STRING-1);
    gets(name);

    printf("Give the address (up to %d characters): ", MAX_STRING - 1);
    gets(address);

    printf("Give the email (up to %d characters): ", MAX_STRING - 1);
    gets(email);

        // check for duplicate email
    b = BST_find_customer(BST_email_root, email);
    if (b)
    {
        printf("Duplicate email. Customer aborted.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    c = (struct customer *) malloc(sizeof(struct customer));
    if (c == 0)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    c->name = strdup(name); // check for memory allocation problem
    if (c->name == 0) return 0;
    c->address = strdup(address);   // check for memory allocation problem
    if (c->address == 0) return 0;
    c->email = strdup(email);   // check for memory allocation problem
    if (c->email == 0) return 0;

    l = (struct double_linked_list*) malloc(sizeof(struct double_linked_list));
    if (l == 0)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory.\n");
        free(c->name);
        free(c->address);
        free(c->email);
        free(c);
        return 0;
    }

    l->data = c;
    l->previous = 0;
    l->next = customers_head;

    if (customers_head)
        customers_head->previous = l;

    customers_head = l;

    if (BST_email_root==NULL)
    {
        BST_email_root = (struct BST_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct BST_node ));

        BST_email_root->data = l;
        BST_email_root->top = NULL;
        BST_email_root->left = NULL;
        BST_email_root->right = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
      new_BST_node(BST_email_root, l);
    }

    return l;
}

void print_customers(struct BST_node *node)
{
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        printf("No customers yet\n");
    }
    else if(node->left)
    {
        print_customers(node->left);
        printf("%s %s %s\n", node->data->data->name,
                             node->data->data->address,
                             node->data->data->email);
        if(node->right)
        {
            print_customers(node->right);
        }
    }
    else if(node->right)
    {
        printf("%s %s %s\n", node->data->data->name,
                             node->data->data->address,
                             node->data->data->email);
        print_customers(node->right);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s %s %s\n", node->data->data->name,
                             node->data->data->address,
                             node->data->data->email);
    }
}

// This function deletes a customer, based on its email
void delete_customer() {
    char email[MAX_STRING];
    struct BST_node *n_del;
    printf("Give the email of the customer you want to delete(up to %d characters) : ", MAX_STRING-1);
    gets(email);

    n_del = BST_find_customer(BST_email_root, email);
    if (n_del==0)
        printf("There is no customer with this email.\n");

    else
    {
        if(n_del->left && n_del->right)
        {
           if(n_del->top->left == n_del)
           {
                n_del->top->left = n_del->left;
           }
           else
           {
                n_del->top->right = n_del->left;
           }

           struct BST_node *node = n_del->left;
           while(node->right)
           {
              node = node->right;
           }
           node->right = n_del->right;
        }
        else if(n_del->left)
        {
           if(n_del->top->left == n_del)
           {
               n_del->top->left = n_del->left;
           }
           else  // must be right node
           {
               n_del->top->right = n_del->left; 
           }
        }
        else if(n_del->right)
        {
           if(n_del->top->left == n_del)
           {
               n_del->top->left = n_del->right;
           }
           else  // must be right node
           {
               n_del->top->right = n_del->right; 
           }
        }
        else {   /* a leaf */
           if(n_del->top->left == n_del)
           {
               n_del->top->left = NULL; 
           }
           else  // must be right node
           {
               n_del->top->right = NULL; 
           }
        }

        free(n_del->data->data->name);
        free(n_del->data->data->email);
        free(n_del->data->data->address);
        free(n_del->data->data);
        free(n_del->data);
        free(n_del);
    }

}


void displaymenu() {
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("1. New customer\n");
    printf("2. Find customer using email\n");
    printf("3. Modify customer\n");
    printf("4. Delete customer\n");
    printf("5. List customers\n");
    printf("0. Exit\n\n");
    printf("Give a choice (0-5) : ");
}

// This function empties the buffer of the standard input (stdin), that is, of the keyboard
void myflush()
{
    char ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
}


// The main function
int main() {
    int choice;
    do {
        displaymenu();
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        myflush();
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            new_customer();
            break;
        case 2:
            find_customer();
            break;
        case 3:
            modify_customer();
            break;
        case 4:
            delete_customer();
            break;
        case 5:
            print_customers(BST_email_root);
            break;

        default:
            printf("Wrong selection.\n\n");
        }
    } while (choice != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i also added a function to list current customers, so you can check the results after each operation. as others pointed out, comparing strcmp result with -1 is incorrect. you should compare the result as == 0, < 0 or > 0.

Comment: the reason i said the double_linked_list is not needed is because the BST_node is already a double linked list, so the double linked list requirement of the exercise is already met.

Comment: I am trying checking your solution! Thanks for the good work! It seems to work in most cases but not all. The program crashes when you delete the first customer that was inserted.. I am digging into this!

Comment: @ritgeo oops! forgot to check n_del->top.  if n_del->top is NULL, it's the root and should be treated differently (but most operations should be same once initial step(s) are taken care of).

Answer (score 1):

After testing the provided source code and inserting the remark of @StephanLechner, the main problem is that the `BST_find_customer()` is not able find any nodes due the gap between the `BST_find_customer()` algorithm and the one used by `new_BST_node()`.

**Error 1** - in the `BST_find_customer()` function, before looking for left or right nodes, explore the `root->data` (a `struct double_linked_list *`).

```
// explore the list from root->data;
struct double_linked_list *ldata = root->data;
while (ldata!=NULL) {
    if (strcmp(email,ldata->data->email)==0) {
        return (root);
    }
    ldata=ldata->next;
}
if (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email)<0) { // ERROR ==-1) {
    return BST_find_customer(root->left,email);
}
else {
    return BST_find_customer(root->right,email);
}
```

Instead of:

```
if (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email)==0)
    return root;
else {
    if (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email)==-1)
        return BST_find_customer(root->left,email);
    else
        return BST_find_customer(root->right,email);
}
```

**Error 2** - In the `BST_delete()` function, check the validity of `root` before exploring its `data`.

> Add the if-condition `(root!=NULL)` in the while-loop to prevent
>   end-of-tree.
>
> The function shall return a value `return (NULL);` instead of
>   `return;`, otherwise undefined behavior.

```
while ((root!=NULL) && (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email)!=0)){ 
    if (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email) < 0){
         father = root;
         root = root->left;
         which_son = 'l';
    } else {
         father = root;
         root = root->right;
         which_son = 'r';
    }
}
if(root==NULL) {
     return (root);
}
```

Instead of:

```
while (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email)!=0) { //first, finding root and remembering who's root father
    if(root==NULL) {
         return root;
    } else if (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email) <0){
         father = root;
         root = root->left;
         if(root==NULL)
            return;
         else which_son = 'l';
    } else {
         father = root;
         root = root->right;
        if(root==NULL)
            return;
        else which_son = 'r';
    }
}
```

**Error 3** - In the `delete_customer()`, abort the deletion when no customer has the entered email.

```
n_del = BST_find_customer(BST_email_root, email);
if (n_del==0) {
    printf("There is no customer with this email.\n");
    return;
}
else
```

Instead of:

```
n_del = BST_find_customer(BST_email_root, email);
if (n_del==0)
    printf("There is no customer with this email.\n");
    // ABORT HERE
else
```

Comment: Thank you for the bug fixes! I have fixed this in my code! Still though i get the same crash! I believe that something is wrong with my root values, and i am trying to figure it out!